# How to recover the inflatable raft in Commandos 2: Men of Courage?

Tags: commandos-2

In Commandos and Commandos BCOD you could recover the inflatable raft using the diver by pressing H (take item shortcut) or clicking on the take item hand icon.

On Commandos 2 I can't find a way to do it, there's no take item shortcut key or an icon to do it.